# Find fixed point of involution of complex projective line

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, involutions

Question: Find fixed points of involution g: $P_1(C) -> P_1(C)$, $g^2$ = Id, if g(2/3) = 3 and g(-2/3)= 1/4

My ideas: to use cross-ratio, maybe we can say g(3) = 2/3 and g(1/4) = -2/3 so we can count cross ratio [3,1/4,2/3,-2/3], but I don't know it can help with finding fixed points

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

An isomorphism of $P^1_\mathbb{C}$ is a 2x2 invertible matrix modulo $\mathbb {C}^*$. The constraints you have give 4 equations :
\begin{align}
g(3)=2/3\\
g(2/3)=3\\
g(-2/3)=1/4\\
g(1/4)=-2/3\end{align}
These should be what you need to determine a representative of $g$ as a matrix.
Then, you will have to find the eigenvectors of your matrix.

Comment: Can you please continue, i don't know what the matrix ${{2/3,3},{1/4,-2/3}}$?

Comment: The matrix acts linearly by $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$. Set $y=1$ and $x$ the entries in the 4 equations : for the first one, you get $3a+b=2/3(3 c+d)$, and so on.